# Wait onLoad inside Multiple Components

Tags: reactjs

I need to render components after I get an answer from onLoad function. Is it possible?

```
var component = this.props.items.map(function(item, index) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = item.src;
    img.onload = function () {
       var width = img.width;
       return <img src={item.src} alt={width} key={index} />
    }
}.bind(this));
```

Comment: Why do you need to render the images after they are loaded?

Comment: @Christiaan , I need to know images orientation before render.

Answer (score 0):

You can preload all images in the constructor of your component. Then when all images finish their onload callback use `setState` to change the state of your component.